# .htaccess limit one folder and one file with one directive

Tags: apache, .htaccess

this does not work - I want to limit one folder and one file with one directive to avaoid that I have to add the allowed IP adresses two times.

```
<Directory .../homes/*/wp-login>
<Files .../homes/*/wp-login.php>
Order deny,allow
deny from all

allow from ...
allow from ...
allow from ...
.
.
.
</Files>
</Directory>
```

With one directive for the file and another one for the folder it works but then the .htaccess file woul get double size. :-(

Comment: Even with separate directives this should not work - not inside an .htaccess file, the context of the `Directory` directive is `server config, virtual host`.

Comment: And even when configured in an appropriate place, these nested directives will behave in an “additive” way, not separately - anything inside would only apply to files matching the Files directive, that are inside the folder the Directory directive specified.